# Angular Material 7.3 mat-card changes

Tags: angular, angular-material-6, angular-material-7

I upgraded from angular 6 to angular 7 and my material

> from:6.2.0
>
> to: 7.3.3

I'm noticing that my mat-card items are showing the border disappeared in the new version but was raised in the older one; the border in the image is gone

[image]

looking at CSS, the older one had a whole box of:

```
<mat-card _ngcontent-c51="" class="mat-card"></mat-card>
```

[image]

Did that style change between the 2 versions? Is there a way to find a comparison of what got changed between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is the culprit.

[feat(elevation): move elevation rules into theme stylesheets (#11344)](https://github.com/angular/material2/commit/9c075f5c50b4d91ad91d4f7fb180f68c5de45cd4#diff-9389c93dca7121685381d0e9e8e96ff3)

> BREAKING CHANGE:
>
> Because `mat-elevation` usages have been moved out of component
>   stylesheets, users who have not invoked a theme mixin will not see any
>   elevation shadows on Material components. However, users that have
>   created a custom theme which lacks the `elevation` property will still
>   see the default black shadows.

**How I found this:**

[card.scss](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/card/card.scss)

I then clicked `history` in the upper right corner to review all commits that impact this file.

[card.scss commit history](https://github.com/angular/material2/commits/master/src/lib/card/card.scss)

The commits on `Sep 18, 2018` is what stood out to me, based on the commit description I suspect this commit is related to what you have described.

Comment: yes, that's what I was looking for, the how. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could go through the **[changelog](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)** , yes it seems to be there are changes on material-card with those versions.

Comment: I already went through that changelog. It doesn't tell me what got changed about mat-card and mat-expansion-panel for example. It is weird they would change functionality without event mentioning it!